# Grab variable outside from within closure

Tags: php, laravel, closures

Considering this closure:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}))->get();
```

How do I pass `$query` to `get()` such as `->get('query')`?

If this is even possible.

**Update**:

This is a follow up to the accepted answer.

Below is the resulting code, for a similar situation, based in `$query->getRelation()` tip.

```
$query = Ticket::with(array('user' => function($q) use ($search) {
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%')->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%');
}));

return $query->whereIn('user_id', $query->getRelation('user')->lists('id'))->paginate(10);
```

Another one of the many ways to achieve it in Eloquent.

Comment: Why do you need to pass to `get` ?

Comment: Is this a framework/class that you wrote? Or are you using an external library? If it is just something that you wrote, have `User::with` return an instance of a class that has `$query` as a property that the `->get()` method can access

Comment: @WereWolf Because I could return an array and use something like `->whereIn('foreign_key', $query)`. But before going to that I'm asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to me but I think you may try this to get the `$query` instance:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}));
$relation = $users->getRelation('posts');
```

The `$relation` will contain an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` (hopefully) but not sure how you use it but you may use `$relation->getForeignKey()` to get the `foreignkey` property. Finally, `$users->get()` will execute the query.

You may also get the relation ($query) object using something like this:

```
$user = User::query();
$relation = $user->getRelation('posts');
dd($relation); // Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
```

*P/S: It's not clear to me what you are going to do so if it helps and you get what you wanted to do then please share the idea/thing in comment. Thanks!*

Comment: It works, I will update the question and show what I was doing.

Comment: You may find this interesting, in my update above, `$query->getRelation('user')->lists('id')` doesn't seem to apply the constraint.

Comment: I like it `Another one of the many ways to achieve it in Eloquent.` +1 :-)